# Can an Applicative instance for this type be created?

Tags: haskell, covariance, applicative, contravariance

As an exploration of how variance works, I've come up with this type that could be both a `Functor` and a `Contravariant` depending on its arguments:

```hs
newtype Shift f g a = Shift { runShift :: f a -> g a }
```

It's similar to `Endo`, except with extra type variables to make the variance of the type ambiguous.

If `f` is covariant and `g` is contravariant, then `Shift f g` is contravariant:

```hs
instance (Functor f, Contravariant g) => Contravariant (Shift f g) where
    contramap f (Shift g) = Shift (contramap f . g . fmap f)
```

And if `f` is contravariant and `g` is covariant, then `Shift f g` is covariant:

```hs
instance (Contravariant f, Functor g) => Functor (Shift f g) where
    fmap f (Shift g) = Shift (fmap f . g . contramap f)
```

It is my understanding that `Divisible` (from `Data.Functor.Contravariant.Divisible` from the `contravariant` package) is to `Contravariant` as `Applicative` is to `Functor`. Using this, `Shift` can be extended to be an instance of `Divisible` as well:

```hs
instance (Functor f, Divisible g) => Divisible (Shift f g) where
    conquer = Shift (const conquer)
    divide f (Shift g) (Shift h) = Shift $
        \x -> case unzipF (fmap f x) of
            (b,c) -> divide f (g b) (h c)
unzipF :: Functor f => f (a,b) -> (f a,f b)
unzipF x = (fmap fst x, fmap snd x)
```

Because the constraint on `Divisible (Shift f g)` is `(Functor f, Divisible g)`, I would expect this to "flip" accordingly for an `Applicative` instance, e.g.

```hs
instance (Contravariant f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Shift f g) where { ... }
```

However, I can't figure out how to fill in the details. My unfinished implementation requires a function like this:

```hs
unzipC :: Contravariant f => f (a,b) -> (f a,f b)
```

but I can't think of a solution to this that doesn't use `fmap`.

Here's the implementation in full:

```hs
instance (Contravariant f, Applicative g) => Applicative (Shift f g) where
    pure x = Shift (const (pure x))
    liftA2 f (Shift g) (Shift h) = Shift $
        \x -> case unzipC (contramap (uncurry f) x) of
            (a,b) -> liftA2 f (g a) (h b)
```

So, does such an `unzipC` even exist? If not, is it still possible to salvage an `Applicative (Shift f g)` instance?

Answer (score 1):

No, such a (total) function can't exist. Observe that it would allow you to construct a value of type `Void`:

```
import Data.Functor.Contravariant
import Data.Void

unzipC :: Contravariant f => f (a,b) -> (f a,f b)
unzipC = undefined

uhoh :: Void
uhoh = getOp (fst $ unzipC $ Op snd) ()
```

Explanation: The type `((), Void) -> Void` is inhabited, by `snd`. `unzipC` would let you get a `() -> Void` and a `Void -> Void` from a `((), Void) -> Void`, but `() -> Void` is obviously uninhabited.

I'm not sure whether there's another way to write the instance you want yet. I'll edit this answer when/if I figure that out.